# Download sources replaced by decompiler?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I recently upgraded from IDEA 13 to 14.

With 13, I would click on a class/method in a third-party jar and see a window that allowed me to download source. Sometimes I would click on "Download Source" and nothing visible would happen; clicking again always brought up the source. A little quirky but ok.

Now, with 14, I click "Download Source" and the yellow bar switches to one item, "Choose Sources". I just want the stuff in Maven like I had before.

What happened? How do I get the old behavior? I don't want decompiled source, I want the original maven source.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: This has been fixed in version 14.0.3**

To your first question "What Happened?", I believe that IntelliJ is failing to automatically download and attach the sources. I am primarily a Gradle user and downloading and attaching sources appears to happen automatically by default so long as the sources are available.

For getting the old behavior back you could do as [suggested by dds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879174/download-sources-replaced-by-decompiler/26905879#26905879) and disable the Java decompiler, this would make "downloaded sources" the only option.

You could also manually download the source files and "attach" them to the project by clicking "choose sources".

There is also an open YouTrack issues for this: [IDEA-132699](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132699). Please add your details to this issue so that JetBrains can better address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check Maven -> Importing -> Automatically download sources.

Also you can try to disable "Java bytecode decompiler" plugin.